# MySQL Query INSERT / SELECT / UPDATE last Row

Tags: mysql, sql

i've 3 MySQL querys in a HTML POST form.
I want to update the last insert ROW i've inserted with my PHP script.

The problem what I've is, it just updates everytime the first row instead the last row i've inserted.

This is my query currently

```
INSERT INTO 
    tbl_orders (name,ordered,number,idcard,account) 
    VALUES 
    (:name,:carID,:number,:idcard,:account);
            
INSERT INTO 
    tbl_money (gesamtWert) 
    SELECT SUM(amount*price) total 
    FROM tbl_prices, tbl_car_pos 
    WHERE cid = :carID AND priceID = productID;

UPDATE 
    tbl_money 
    SET tbl_money.orderID = (SELECT tbl_orders.orderID FROM tbl_orders ORDER BY tbl_orders.orderID DESC LIMIT 1) 
    ORDER BY 
        orderID 
    DESC LIMIT 1;
```

First query selects the values of the form action and insert it into the first table.

Second one is SUM the total price of the car and insert it into the second table.

Third one should now select the last insert row of the first query and update the last insert row from the second query. but as I said it updates the first row.

Lets say i've inserted the last row with ID: 10 and insert now a new row with ID: 11, the third query will update the ID: 1 instead of ID:11.
So if anyone can tell me where my problem is would be amazing.

Comment: The second query seems to be missing a join criteria between the two tables in the `from` clause. Please provide sample data and desired results to clarify your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrate 3rd query into 2nd.

Without optimization, using direct insert:

```sql
INSERT INTO 
    tbl_orders (name,ordered,number,idcard,account) 
    VALUES 
    (:name,:carID,:number,:idcard,:account);

INSERT INTO 
    tbl_money (gesamtWert, orderID) 
    SELECT SUM(amount*price), 
           (SELECT tbl_orders.orderID FROM tbl_orders ORDER BY tbl_orders.orderID DESC LIMIT 1)
    FROM tbl_prices, tbl_car_pos 
    WHERE cid = :carID AND priceID = productID;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use PHP, there is a function that returns the last inserted ID.

https://www.php.net/manual/ro/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Comment: It is more efficient than using a slow select ;) And if you use transactions, you can be sure that you'll get that ID, and not another one inserted by a another parallel query that is executed at the "same" time.